# Combining Image3D and Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d, image

I want to combine an `Image3D` and a `Graphics3D` using `Show`. Here is the code:

```
data = Table[
   Abs[((3 - 3 z) (.5 Sign[3 - 3 z] + .5)) (x Sin[x] + y Cos[y])],
   {x, 0, 15, .1}, {y, 0, 10, .1}, {z, 0, 3, .1}
   ];
Show[Image3D[data/Max@data], 
 Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[5], Blue, 
   Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2}, {8, 5, 2}, {14, 9, 2}, {15, 
      10, 0}}]}]]
```

While the coordinates are aligned, the output is not.

[image: 3d path overlap]

See the blue line on the right corner. How can I fix the problem?

**Edit:**
The issue is resolved. There are two answers below. Both are helpful but neither of them is complete. Once any of them is competed, I'll mark it as accepted. I write one possible answer to the question here (I added `{#[[3]], #[[2]], #[[1]]}/delta & /@ pointList` to my code):

```
With[{delta = .1},
 data = Table[
   Abs[((3 - 3 z) (.5 Sign[3 - 3 z] + .5)) (x Sin[x] + y Cos[y])],
   {x, 0, 15, delta}, {y, 0, 10, delta}, {z, 0, 3, delta}
   ];
 Show[Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[5], Blue, 
    Line[{#[[3]], #[[2]], #[[1]]}/
       delta & /@ {{0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2}, {8, 5, 2}, {14, 9,
         2}, {15, 10, 0}}]}], Image3D[data/Max@data]]
 ]
```

Comment: Maybe you'll have better luck with the alignment if you use `Raster3D[]` instead...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> While the coordinates are aligned

Unfortunately, they are not because the moment you create a `Image3D`, the coordinate system is different. Usually, if your image has the dimensions $n_x \times n_y \times n_z$ the coordinate system of your volume ranges from `{{1,nx},{1,ny},{1,nz}}` depending on the implementation.

If you want to combine an `Image3D` and some other stuff, you have to rescale your coordinates. This can be done using `RescalingTransform`:

```
data = Reverse@Table[
   Abs[((3 - 3 z) (.5 Sign[3 - 3 z] + .5)) (x Sin[x] + y Cos[y])], {z,
     0, 3, .1}, {y, 0, 10, .1}, {x, 0, 15, .1}];
img3d = Image3D[data/Max@data];
rescale = 
  RescalingTransform[{{0, 15}, {0, 10}, {0, 3}}, 
   Transpose[{{1, 1, 1}, ImageDimensions[img3d]}]];
Show[img3d, 
 Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[5], Blue, 
   Line[rescale /@ {{0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2}, {8, 5, 2}, {14, 
       9, 2}, {15, 10, 0}}]}], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Additionally, I'm pretty sure you think your `Table` call does something different. Please note the following:

```
Table[0, {x, 5}, {y, 6}, {z, 7}] // Dimensions
```

This gives a volume having dimension z=5, y=6 and x=7! If you look at my `Table` call in the code, you see that I reversed the iterators.

At last, please note that data in `Image` and `Image3D` is usually in reverse order compared to the usual coordinate system.

Comment: You beat me! but there still axes problem as described by cormullion. I used `Line[1/0.1 {#[[3]], 10 - #[[2]], 15 - #[[1]]} & /@ lineNodes]` to transform them.

Comment: @Silvia Look at my `Table` call. What people forget is, that `Table[0, {x, 5}, {y, 6}, {z, 7}]` does **not** the expected thing. Dimension is reversed! Maybe I should add this to the post.

Comment: You are right Silvia. I realized the same thing. See my comment under cormullion's answer.

Comment: @halirutan Sorry I didn't notice it. But I think it should be `{z, 3, 0, -.1}`? Compare the composed result with that composed with say `ContourPlot3D` and the line graphics.

Comment: @Silvia Yes, this is maybe true. I didn't know what to OP wanted but the first dimension in Image/Image3D is reversed.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the problem (and this may not be an answer), but I noticed the axes were different:

```
Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[5], Blue, 
  Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2}, {8, 5, 2}, {14, 9, 2}, 
  {15, 10, 0}}]},  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: plot 1]

```
Image3D[data/Max@ data, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: plot 2]

Comment: Thanks cormullion. I noticed the same issue. A simple transform on the line points resolves the issue: `{#[[3]], #[[2]], #[[1]]}/delta & /@ pointList`. But I wonder if it is a bug?

Comment: The docs say 'slices, rows, and columns' correspond to x, y, and z..., so it may be deliberate. @halirutan as usual knows what's going on.

Comment: @Mohsen I don't consider it as a bug. IMO `Image3D`, like `Image`, uses coordinates like `Array`/`Matrix`, which is different from `Graphics` by convention.

Answer (score 3):

Everybody seems happy already at the time of this answer. But the following resources will help a newcomer develop good habits:

- [Volume Rendering And Processing](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/VolumeRenderingAndProcessing.html)
- [`Image3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Image3D.html) (esp. the section [Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Image3D.html#DetailsAndOptions))