# Image3D and Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d, image3d

also I guess that the topic was tackled in [Combining Image3D and Graphics3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23766/combining-image3d-and-graphics3d). My question is quite similar: How do I match the coordinate Systems of Graphics3D and Image3D?

Here some code:

```
z = 1;
p = RandomInteger[100, {z, 3}];
r = RandomInteger[10, {z}];
spheres = MapThread[RotateLeft[DiskMatrix[#1, {100, 100, 100}], #2] &, {r, p}];
i = Image3D[Plus @@ spheres, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
obj = GraphicsComplex[p, Sphere[Range[z], r]];
gr = Graphics3D[obj,
                Axes -> True,
                AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
                PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}, {0, 100}}]
Show[i, gr, Axes -> True]
```

Can anyone explain to me how to match the coordinate systems, that the spheres match?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems related to this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23766/combining-image3d-and-graphics3d

Comment: @xslittlegrass: yes, i know. but i cant solve it with that.

Comment: i guess you need to elaborate on whats different. Looks like a duplicate question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you need to apply `{50,50,50}` shift to `DiskMatrix`. It is because `DiskMatrix` produces sphere with the center at `{50,50,50}`.

`Image3D` has different axes directions than `Graphics3D` so you need to search through numerous variants of transpositions and reflections. I found the following combination:

```
z = 10;
p = RandomInteger[100, {z, 3}];
r = RandomInteger[10, {z}];

spheres = 
  MapThread[
   Transpose[#, {3, 2, 1}] &@Reverse@RotateLeft[
       DiskMatrix[#1, {100, 100, 100}], #2 - {50, 50, 50}] &, {r, p}];
i = Image3D[Plus @@ spheres, Axes -> True, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];
obj = GraphicsComplex[p, Sphere[Range[z], r]];
gr = Graphics3D[obj, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}, {0, 100}}];
Show[i, gr, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Much nicer way to do the geometric transformations than what I proposed with `GeometricTransformation`.

Answer (score 1):

This still may be considered a duplicate, but it's also possible that there is something odd happening with the formation of `spheres`.  A set of geometric transformations (rotations, reflections and finally a scaling) gives close to overlap.  Note I got rid of the randomness to make this problem a bit easier to navigate and did not nest the `GeometricTransformations` so that each one could be visualized if desired.

```
z = 5;
p = {{50, 50, 50}, {10, 10, 10}, {90, 90, 10}, {90, 10, 90}, {10, 90, 
    90}};
r = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
spheres = 
  MapThread[RotateLeft[DiskMatrix[#1, {100, 100, 100}], #2] &, {r, p}];
i = Image3D[Plus @@ spheres, Axes -> True, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];
obj = GraphicsComplex[p, Sphere[Range[z], r]];
gr = Graphics3D[obj, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}, {0, 100}}];
objreflected = 
  GeometricTransformation[obj, 
   ReflectionTransform[{0, 0, 1}, {50, 50, 50}]];
objrotated = GeometricTransformation[
   GeometricTransformation[objreflected, 
    RotationTransform[180 Degree, {1, 0, 0}, {50, 50, 50}]],
   RotationTransform[100 Degree, {0, 1, 0}, {50, 50, 50}]];
objscaled = 
  GeometricTransformation[objrotated, 
   ScalingTransform[{0.4, 0.4, 0.4}, {50, 50, 50}]];
Show[i, Graphics3D@objscaled]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why the central sphere gets blown up in the `image3d` portion of the graphic is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question.

I don't quite understand how you built the `Image3D` object.  I notice that the sphere doesn't seem to go where you put the points.  For example, if I put the point right in the middle of the coordinate system, they end up out at the corners

```
p = {{50, 50, 50}};
r = {10};
spheres = 
  MapThread[RotateLeft[DiskMatrix[#1, {100, 100, 100}], #2] &, {r, p}];
i = Image3D[Plus @@ spheres, Axes -> True, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, ImageSize -> 300];
obj = GraphicsComplex[p, Sphere[Range[z], r]];
gr = Graphics3D[obj, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}, {0, 100}}, ImageSize -> 300];
Grid[{{i, 
   gr}, {Show[i, gr, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 300, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}], SpanFromLeft}}]
```

[image]

So if I try to recreate what I think you are going for, I do the following

```
p1 = N[p[[1]]];
r1 = N[r[[1]]];
table = Table[
   If[EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, p1] <= r1, 1, 0], {z, 100}, {y, 
    100}, {x, 100}];
i2 = Image3D[table, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Looks good, but if you try to use a less symmetric point as the center of the sphere, it gets all wonky (that's a technical term).

```
p1 = {10.0, 20.0, 30.0};
r1 = N[r[[1]]];
table = Table[
   If[EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, p1] <= r1, 1, 0], {z, 100}, {y, 
    100}, {x, 100}];

i2 = Image3D[table, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

I don't understand why, but the only way I can get `Image3D` to work is to apply `Reverse` to two of the axes.  The following works:

```
z = 1;
p = RandomInteger[100, {z, 3}];
r = RandomInteger[10, {z}];
i = Module[{p1, r1, table},
   p1 = N[p[[1]]];
   r1 = N[r[[1]]];
   table = 
    Table[If[EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, p1] <= r1, 1, 0], {z, 
      100}, {y, 100}, {x, 100}];
   Image3D[Reverse[table, {1, 2}], Axes -> True, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]];
obj = GraphicsComplex[p, Sphere[Range[z], r]];
gr = Graphics3D[obj, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}, {0, 100}}];
Show[i, gr, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

To me, `Image3D` is too buggy to use.  Half the time I try to do something with it, it crashes my kernel.  I want there to be a cool `ListDensityPlot3D` function, but I'll have to wait I think.